# How long does it take to perform the initial update?

Tags: setup, operating-systems, update

I just ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` on my pi to update for the first time. It's still going at it, and I was just wondering if I should be worried since it's been 1 hour and I keep getting this strange update loop below. What's going on and is it safe to just/should I just pull the plug?

```
ldconfig: /usr/lib/icelib/libicecore.so.1 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

ldconfig: /usr/lib/icelib/libicecore.so.1.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

ldconfig: /usr/lib/icelib/libicecore.so is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

ldconfig: /usr/lib/icelib/libicecore.so.1 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

ldconfig: /usr/lib/icelib/libicecore.so.1.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes about 30 minutes max to update if you have a decent connection. I just did one but it depends on wethre you have lots of updates or just a few. First time update is what I did and took about 15 minutes.

As to is it safe to unplug, that depends, update is normally two stages. The first stage it downloads the files and you can abort that with no issues and will resume from where you stopped.

The second stage is when it installs. Less safe to abort and wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: It's finally escaped that strange loop, and is now 'setting up' a myriad of files, so I guess I'm in the clear. Do updates wipe my files? I'm both a novice to Linux and Raspi so I've been a little antsy.

Comment: @MonteCarlo Yes, updates "replace" old files. After a reboot the new files will active. I have been updating a variety of linux distros and the only thing that goes wrong is the Video driver. But, as you are running the raspberry distro you are 99% safe

Comment: And so you were correct! Just ended! Thank you so much!